# Bluetooth RFCOMM connection: read serial data from com port in Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth, serial-port, rfcomm

I am working with the Android Bluetooth Chat sample application. I am trying to read serial data from the Android device in Windows 7.

I have been able to pair the Android device to the Bluetooth adapter on my laptop. I replaced the UUID in the sample application with the following per some other discussions:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

When I run the Android application I am able to connect to the laptop. In the "Hardware" properties of my Android device there is a "Device Function" entry called "Standards Serial over Bluetooth link (COM10)". When I attempt to connect CoolTerm to COM10 I receive "error 1168" (there is no additional description for the error).

Am I misunderstanding something about the process of sending serial data via Bluetooth to a Windows com port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you are selecting the **correct** COM. In my last Android application that required SPP (Serial Port Profile) Bluetooth communication, when Windows 7 paired I had several COM's open up.

[image: Picture of BT settings with all the COMs that were created]

If COM10 is not working, verify that it is the "incoming" COM (or maybe it's outgoing, I can't remember b/c it's been a few months).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both of the COM ports listed without success. I later replaced the WIDCOMM BT drivers I was using with the BlueSoleil stack and am now able to read the correct COM port. I would prefer to be able to read the COM port while using any BT drivers, but for now using BlueSoleil is an adequate solution.

Comment: Don't know whether you *want* to talk to a COM port on Windows, or what environment you're programming in.  But the 32feet.NET library that I maintain makes it easy to create a server in .NET that the Android app can connect to, see e.g. http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bluetooth%20Server-side  I hate the complexities of setting up COM ports so like the programmatic system, and we support stacks from MSFT, Widcomm and BlueSoleil etc.

Comment: Thanks @alanjmcf; this time setting up the COM port myself was adequate, but I will keep your library in mind for future applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the proper Bluetooth API from your Windows application to call and connect to your Android device, that is:

1. do an 'Inquiry' of all nearby devices, discoverable and exposing an SPP service/profile (SPP=Serial Profile Protocole). This profile has the aforementioned GUID {00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}
2. once all found, select the one you're searching for (either by Name or MacAdress)
3. at this point, you can do a 'Discovery' of its Services and check out that it has the proper service exposed (SPP or RFCOMM)
4. then connect to it, using the Bluetooth socket API...